# Alerts and if statements - Xcode

Tags: xcode, if-statement, uitextfield, alert

I'm trying to trigger an alert with an if statement. but the code im using wont do what i want.

This is one attempt at triggering the alert

```
-(Void)ShowAlert
     if (mainInt == 120) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

i have declared 'ShowAlert' in the .h file as -(void)ShowAlert just under my -(IBAction) declares.

But still no alert when ran in simulator. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!

THANKS

(I'm am using Xcode 4.6.2)

Comment: How are you calling -ShowAlert? And are you saying that -ShowAlert itself is never called? or that -ShowAlert is called, but then the UIAlertView isn't shown?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **if (mainInt == 120)** is never true.

I would try with an **ELSE** if i were you. And log whole process about what's going on like this:

```
-(void)ShowAlert{
     if (mainInt == 120){
        NSLog(@"TRUE i should see the alertview! , mainInt = %i",mainInt);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
     }else{
     NSLog(@"FALSE , mainInt = %i",mainInt);
     }
}
```

Comment: The use of the else statement that you provided still did not trigger the alert. any other suggestions?

Comment: So you never get the alert nor the else log? Are you sure -ShowAlert is even being called? Have you run under the debugger, set a breakpoint at the start of -ShowAlert, and seen if you hit it or not?  Again, how are you calling -ShowAlert?

Comment: +1 i agree with john it's a high possibility that -showalert is never called.